# Meaning of "it's like moist black velvet." (From The Most Dangerous Game)

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Can't see it," remarked Rainsford, trying to peer through the dank tropical night that was palpable as it pressed its thick warm blackness in upon the yacht.
>
> "You've good eyes," said Whitney, with a laugh," and I've seen you pick off a moose moving in the brown fall bush at four hundred yards, but even you can't see four miles or so through a moonless Caribbean night."
>
> "Nor four yards," admitted Rainsford. "Ugh! **It's like moist black velvet**."

What does that mean **it's like moist black velvet.**?

Comment: This is a simile. Have you looked up "moist" and "velvet"?

Comment: << The dank [unpleasantly **cold** and damp according to Lexico, Collins, CED, Macmillan; Webster's has 'usually chilly' ... : this doesn't work, accepting this  definition] tropical night that was palpable [one could almost feel it as say a curtain] and pressed its thick _warm_ (!) blackness in upon ... >> has already explained this (apart from the questionable use of 'dank').

Comment: It's already been described as *a **dank** tropical night* - that's why it's *like **moist** velvet*. What is it about this question that couldn't be answered using any dictionary?

Comment: yes.I know what ''black velvet'' means. and I know this sentence is a simile. but when we comibe it with moist, the conclusion is not clear.

Comment: It's just a bad-writer, wordy way of saying "it's very black".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No, it not. First of all: it is not bad writing to use good similes. Second: It does not just mean "it's very black". If you look below at my answer you will see it does not just mean that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Heavens....are you saying that Richard Connell is a bad writer and _The Most Dangerous Game_ (1924)  is badly written? It's been required reading in most American high schools since like, forever.

Comment: The New York Times said of Connell that “the very tricks which have given him a large and remunerative public have continued to rob him of the critical rewards which come to a man of his talents if he devote them to a shrewder and more critical study of the contemporary scene.”

Answer (score -1):

The definition of velvet:
vel·vet
/ˈvelvət/
noun
a closely woven fabric of silk, cotton, or nylon, that has a thick short pile on one side.

The definition of black:
black
/blak/

1. of the very darkest color owing to the absence of or complete absorption of light; the opposite of white.

The definition of moist:
moist
/moist/
adjective
slightly wet; damp or humid.
"the air was moist and heavy"

The simile "moist black velvet" is using sensory language. The sense of sight is applied by using the word "black" and the sense of touch is applied with "moist" because it helps describe the ocean. The third word, "velvet" is also used as a sense of touch, helping describe the smooth soft texture of the night, with the word "velvet".

This link here will help describe this exact simile:
https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/richard-connells-most-dangerous-game-what-some-508021

The following links should help with similes and metaphors:
https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-similes.html
https://examples.yourdictionary.com/metaphor-examples.html